# Asynchronous Messaging Protocol compatibility outside Python (and twisted)

Tags: twisted, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

The Asynchronous Messaging Protocol is a simple protocol in python-twisted. I have a fairly complete app (python, twisted, kivy) using it. The client-server architecture implements a view-controller sort of relationship, with allmost all business logic server-side and the UI interface code simply reflecting change in state of models (sent by server) and sending the appropriate AMP messages.

[Here is a list of implementations of the AMP protocol in other languages](https://amp-protocol.net/Implementations/), but some seen unfinished, and most don't seem to be actually being used for anything serious.

The use-case I'm looking at is a fully Python app which currently works on Windows, Linux, and Android (possibly iOS if I ever get round to building that). And possibly, in the future, replacing the View/UI bit with 'native' language (Java/Swift on Android, for instance) while keeping the business bits in python and twisted.

So I have two main questions:-

1. Is it accurate to say that AMP is only really used within python-twisted and those programs that use it?
2. Are there other, more generally useful network protocols which are both implemented and fairly easy to use in twisted as well as being non-specific (e.g. jabber is really only for chat)? Preferably which don't require a server like WAMP/autobahn do (if I understand correctly) so it can be self-contained within any device which can run python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This isn't entirely accurate. Twisted just happens to use it the most. Other languages make use of AMP, it's just that AMP hasn't become very popular given popularity of other more robust options like AMQP (ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, WebsphereMQ, etc).
2. AMP is about as simple as it can get. Also, it's unlikely you will find a solution without a server.

AMP is not locked to Twisted or Python. There are other implementations in other languages but like you said some are not used in a "serious" manner and often go unmaintained. Don't let that scare you off because the protocol is so simple, there often isn't much to do after it's been implemented. You will be happy to know that the actual protocol hasn't changed much and isn't very difficult to implement in any language if you follow the design. If you want something more generic, cross platform, and ensured compatibility, then consider HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks. If the message queue solutions are currently more popular, is there still a use case for new-ish apps to go for AMP rather than what is more commonly used? And I did consider HTTP request but it would seem the overhead for that would be fairly significant (as I'm running on mobile as well this is a rather important factor, my AMP messages have hit the 64k limit multiple times already, hence I've already implemented my own split-and-send).

Comment: I think AMP has valid use cases for newer apps. It's small, well defined, and portable. Other solutions, including AMQP, have more overhead.

Comment: Looks like I'd have to rig up some testing for overhead then. Thanks, will let this sit for a while but I think this answer can be accepted after that.